# Hibernate flush() and Cascade.PERSIST

Tags: hibernate, cascade, flush, object-state

I have been working on Hibernate since sometime and I never really paid attention to the flush() method until yesterday.

I understand that flush() is invoked automatically when the transaction is committed.

I am working on a sample Library Management System. The relation between *Authors* and *Books* is *ManyToMany*

In Author.java

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
```

In Book.java

```
@ManyToMany
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
       name="BookAuthor",
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bookId", referencedColumnName="id")},
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="authorId", referencedColumnName="id")}
      )
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();
```

There is a mapping table *BookAuthor* in the database.

This is what I am doing.

1. Set FlushMode to MANUAL
2. Get a Book from the database
3. Create a new Author. (Transient)
4. Add author to the *authors* Set in the Book instance.
5. Begin Transaction
6. Update book instance
7. Commit transaction.

Contrary to my expectation, I notice that updating the Book has **NOT** propagated and persisted the transient Author instance. The Author instance is still transient.

Now, if I set the **FlushMode to AUTO(default)**, not only is the transient Author committed but a relation is also created in the BookAuthor table.

I am surprised to know that flush() has such an important role to play.

Am I doing something wrong?

Regards,

Shardul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flush` is the method that writes changes to the database. Without flushing, nothing is written. So obviously, if you set flush mode to manual and never call flush, nothing will be written to the database.

Comment: OH, I was under the impression that when I commit the transaction the changes are written to the database. BTW, what is the equivalent of flush() when I am not using Hibernate?

Comment: But then when I set FlushMode to Manual and simply save/persist a simple Object, it works fine even if I don't flush. How does it work in this scenario?

Comment: See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-flushing. It's probably written to the database because you're using native ID generation. The quivalent of flush in JPA is... flush. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29. There is no equivalent in pure JDBC, since JDBC doesn't have the notion of persistent objects held in a in-memory session cache.